# Junit testing for Rest crud operation

Tags: java, rest, junit

I have a 4 rest api for crud operations. So when I am writing a junit for those rest api's,

1.Should I write a single test case which do all the crud operation or it should be different test cases for each rest api?

2.I'f I write separate test case, then is it ok to use the record created in create test case in the update or get test cases. In that case there is a dependency between each test cases.

3.How can I enforce to Junit to run test cases on implement order given that my test case method are not in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2):

DISCLAIMER: there is no "one right answer".

SUGGESTIONS:

1. If at all possible, you should code your JUnit tests so that each runs *independently*.  There should not be any "ordering" dependency between any specific test.
2. All things being equal, I would recommend a *different* test for each operation.
3. I would also recommend liberal use of [fixtures](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Test-fixtures), or a Mock object library like [Mockito](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html).
4. Failing all else, Junit 4.11 and higher offers [@FixMethodOrder annotation](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/doc/ReleaseNotes4.11.md#test-execution-order)